# Install Windows 7 but keep recovery partitions in dell

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, partition-recovery

I have purchased a dell insiron 5521 and had windows 8 preinstalled in it. I wanted to install windows 7 x64 so i disabled the secure boot and started the install. When it asks where to install windows it shows the partitions:

Disk 0 Partition 1: ESP 500MB (System)         //now is unallocated space

Disk 0 Partition 2: DIAGS 40MB (OEM Reserved)

Disk 0 Partition 3: 128MB MSR (Reserved)         //now is unallocated space

Disk 0 Partition 4: Winretools 500MB (OEM Reserved)

Disk 0 Partition 5: OS 451.9GB Primary        //now is unallocated space

Disk 0 Partition 6: PBR Image 12.7GB (OEM Reserved)

I deleted the partition 1,3,5 and they appear now as unallocated spaces (3 different).
I want to keep the recovery files in case i ever want to go back to windows 8.

But when i choose a partition to install in the os it shows "Windos cannot be instelled in this partition - Show details" and when i press to see the details it says "The selected disk is of the gpd partition style".

So I cannot install it anywhere!!!
What exactly are the rest partitions? How can I bypass this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you booted the Win7 DVD in UEFI mode?

Comment: I could not go back to restore my pc and could not install windows 7 at all when i kept these partitions. The solution was to erase all of the partitions and install then windows 7. I have kept the key to windows 8 and i guess i can install windows 8 again when i need it with the key i have, i will just have to manually download all the drivers... Thank you...